# Using solid color photos on solid color background

Tags: color, composition

I've been trying to figure out how to get this to look right for the past week.

We just got permission from a photographer to use some of her excellent photos of vegan food. Here's one:

[image: vegan pancakes]

However, we also have an orange background that corresponds to the orange of the respective icon which leads to this page.

[image]

I just can't figure out how to get this to look right on the orange page. Is there anything I can do around the photo to get away from its current gawdy appearance?

[image: everything together]

Answer (score 5):

You could add a border or drop shadow (or both!):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that mockup. I had initially done that, actually. I can't remember why I got rid of it, but now that I'm seeing it again, it does seem to work pretty well. Maybe I'll revert back to that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative might be to apply rounded corners to your photos? Add a hover to the image to display the caption. The roundness keeps in sync with your nice icons and great font choice for the page heading.

[image]

**On hover display caption**

[image]